# What sort of locking strategy do I need to prevent race conditions here?

Tags: mysql, sql, locking, innodb

I'm working on a competition website where the prize draw logic is reasonably simple: every 220th entry should be a winner.

I've briefly outlined the process here:

```sql
-- create new entry row
INSERT INTO entries (...) VALUES (...); -- returns 456 as the newly created id

-- get last winner
SELECT id
  FROM entries
 WHERE winner = 1
ORDER
    BY created DESC
 LIMIT 1;

-- see how many entries there have been since
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM entries
 WHERE id >  123 -- id selected in last query
   AND id <= 456; -- id of newly created entry

-- if count = 220
UPDATE entries
   SET winner = 1
 WHERE id = 456;
```

The above logic doesn't take into account the possibility of race conditions. What sort of locking do I need to use to prevent race conditions from occurring?

(I'm using MySQL/InnoDB.)

Comment: How many entrants are you expecting? Could you lock a one row, one column table, that holds the number of entrants, in exclusive mode for a few milliseconds when ever anyone enters?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using some programming language, here is some pseudo-code:

```
$last = SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl WHERE winner=1;
UPDATE tbl SET winner=1 WHERE id > $last LIMIT 1 OFFSET 220;
```

There are no race conditions because the UPDATE will, at worst, set `winner` when it is already set.

Are you doing this code each time a row is entered?  That could be turned into a TRIGGER and avoid the UPDATE.  Instead it would set `NEW.winner = 1` depending on a `SELECT`.

If, instead, you are doing in periodically, then you would need to repeat the sequence of code until it no longer UPDATEs any rows (rows_affected()).  This would allow for, say 2*220 entrants since the last update.  You could turn the code into a Stored Procedure.

It would be good to have

```
INDEX(winner, id)
```